# SHGetKnownFolderPath hangs

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I have a Win32 application (not console app) written in C that uses a call to SHGetKnownFolderPath to add an entry to the common programs menu. I have noticed that it hangs indefinitely on some systems randomly. Up until now, I have just killed/restarted the program to fix the issue, but now it will not work at all on my machine.

Another part of the mystery is that they problem only occurs when the executable is built on my dedicated build server. I do not see the issue if I build the application locally.

Anyone got any thoughts?

Comment: Create a user-mode dump when the program has stopped making forward progress for offline analysis. You can use Task Manager to create a mini dump.

Comment: Difficult to say w/o some reproducing code. Even if this code doesn't reproduce the error, some code could be useful. What folder are you getting information for? Getting a known folder uses this registry key: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\[your kf guid], you can check if it looks ok. You can also use IKnownFolderManager instead https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iknownfoldermanager which may give different results

Comment: Have you allowed for known folders in foreign languages? Does your application fully support Unicode UTF-16 or are you using MBCS ?

Comment: I compared the registry key on machines where the code works vs my machine where it does not work, and they are identical. I'm trying to get IKnownFolderManager working, but it is fighting me a bit.

Comment: I'm puzzled. Why do you avoid diagnosing what the issue is?

Comment: @iinspectable What do you mean? I definitely want to diagnose the problem.

Comment: That was in response to your statement of trying to get a competing implementation working. That may or may not be a solution. In order to know you're going to have to understand your current implementation. As recommended earlier, pull a user-mode dump. Or, even better, if you can, capture a time travel debugging trace. A TTD trace will always contain all necessary information to exhaustively diagnose the root cause of an issue.

Comment: That's a fair point. The whole implementation swap wasn't the "solution" in my mind, just another data point.

I made some progress this morning. I was able to get a debug version of the executable to display the same problem and actually attach the debugger. It appears to be a deadlock issue. This app runs without opening a window and makes all calls in WinMain. I think it is Loader Lock.

Comment: You neither need a debug version, nor a debugger. Task Manager allows you to pull a minidump as it is. A minidump of a deadlock allows you to understand, which threads are involved and which resources they are waiting for. A TTD trace allows you to understand how you arrived in this situation.